# Why isn't this UIButton visible in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, gui, monogame

I'm trying to implement buttons into my game. I noticed iOS has the `UIButton` class, which I tried, but upon drawing it nothing is shown. The asset image is properly loaded, I've checked this. The `SpriteBatch` isn't drawing on top of the buttons either. `Draw` is properly being called on every frame. The button's enabled property is set to `True`.

The code, simplified:

```
private List buttons;
```

public void AddButtons()
        {
            UIButton b = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
            b.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle("icon.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            b.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, 256, 256);
            buttons.Add(b);
        }

`public void Draw()
    {
        foreach (UIButton b in buttons)
        {
            b.Draw(b.Frame);
        }
    }`

Why isn't it visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point in the code above do you call the equivalent of [addSubView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a), which I think (assuming `this` is a `UIView`) should be `this.AddSubView(b)`.

Pre-supposing Xamarin's iOS implementation works the same way that the underlying Objective-C APIs work, you would also no longer need to explicitly call the `Draw` method of the buttons because that will be handled by the UI Kit machinery that Xamarin's API is wrapping.